# How can i merge objects on the basis of same value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have array of multiple objects. Every object have a key "id". I want to merge objects On the basis of same value of "id".

```
var obj = [{'id': 1, 'title': 'Hi'}, {'id': 1, 'description': 'buddy'}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'come'}, {'id': 2, 'description': 'On'}]

And i want output something like that

var new_obj = [{'id': 1, 'title': 'Hi' 'description': 'buddy'}, {id: 2, 'title': 'come', 'description': 'on'}]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

This way works :

```js
let toMerge = [{'id': 1, 'title': 'Hi'}, {'id': 1, 'description': 'buddy'}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'come'}, {'id': 2, 'description': 'On'}]
let merged = []

for ( let object of toMerge ) {
    // if object not already merged
    if(!merged.find(o => o.id === object.id)) {
        // filter the same id's objects, merge them, then push the merged object in merged array
        merged.push(toMerge.filter(o => o.id === object.id).reduce((acc, val) => {return {...acc, ...val}}))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could reduce the array by finding an object with the same `id` and assign the object to found or take a new object.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, title: 'Hi' }, { id: 1, description: 'buddy' }, { id: 2, title: 'come' }, { id: 2, description: 'On' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(({ id }) => o.id === id);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = {});
        Object.assign(temp, o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

## Here's a solution

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Hi"
    },
    {
        description: "buddy",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "come"
    },
    {
        description: "On",
        id: 2
    }
]

const f = (data) => 
  Object.values(data.reduce(
    (y, x) => ({
      ...y, 
      [x.id]: {
        ...x, 
        ...(y[x.id] || {})
      },
    }),
    {},
  ))
console.log(f(data))
```

## Here's a solution using Ramda.js

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Hi"
    },
    {
        description: "buddy",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "come"
    },
    {
        description: "On",
        id: 2
    }
]

const f = R.compose(R.values, R.reduceBy(R.merge, {}, R.prop('id')))

console.log(f(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```